# Android preview image crop helloyako:imagecropview

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, crop

Imagecropview like instagram library [https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop](https://github.com/naver/android-imagecropview) to crop image but i have a problem with the crop box which is too small.

[Result Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B15qc8-CjNWqd1BVOXJxeWxQOUk/view)

**XML code:**

```
<com.naver.android.helloyako.imagecrop.view.ImageCropView
    xmlns:imagecrop="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/imageView_pic_upload_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    imagecrop:gridInnerStroke="1dp"
    imagecrop:gridInnerColor="#66ffffff"
    imagecrop:setOuterGridMode="on"
    imagecrop:gridOuterStroke="3dp"
    imagecrop:gridOuterColor="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

How can i make it large and centralized it.
Thanks